# How to get a master table record by count of detail table records without top(1)

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, count

I have a master table (Team) and a detail table (TeamMember).  TeamMember has a FK to Team.
I need to get the Team record for the team that has the most team members.  I at first had

```
SELECT team.name
FROM   team
       INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) AS membercount,
                          teamID
                   FROM   teammember
                   GROUP BY teamID
                   ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS team_with_most_members
         ON team.id = team_with_most_members.teamID
```

I was informed that I cannot use TOP(1) in my queries.  Anyone have an idea how I can do it without?

Thanks!

```
Team
ID, Name

TeamMember
ID, TeamID, UserID
```

Comment: And what do you want to do if there is a tie? But I'm more interested in the answer to @JNK's question.

Comment: @Dan - then whoever told you that doesn't know a lot about databases...

Comment: I think that's why @Dan used quotes. :-)

Comment: @Dan please see the results of my testing: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/15/why-generalizations-are-dangerous.aspx - this is why generalizations are dangerous and you should always test. As it turns out your TOP 1 wasn't all that bad after all, and performs on par with my solution (and about twice as good as Wil's).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is crude but it works:

```
SELECT t.name
FROM team AS t
JOIN teammember AS tm ON tm.teamID = t.ID
GROUP BY t.Name
HAVING COUNT(tm.id) = (SELECT MAX(members) FROM (SELECT COUNT(id) members FROM teammember GROUP BY teamid) AS sub)
```

Comment: I agree with you 100%, but I ended up using this one.

Comment: @Dan since the goal of this exercise was to provide a query that improved performance over TOP 1, did you actually test that the accepted solution did so? I did: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/15/why-generalizations-are-dangerous.aspx Not trying to one-up anybody, but you are actually changing your code from probably the most optimal solution to one that is going to perform twice as worse. To quote Ron Burgundy, "Milk was a bad choice."

Comment: Maybe that'll teach them to not artificially restrict their dev's decisions ;)

Comment: If you are referring to my original question when you say exercise, then I must correct you - the goal was not to find a query to improve performance.  It was simply to do the requested resultset without using a top(1).  In this specific case, performance is not a concern (strange that may seem).  This was purely an assigned exercise to get familiar with a new database at a new place of employment.

Comment: @Dan you originally came back with saying you can't use TOP 1 because of performance (citing John Samson's article). So it doesn't make sense that you are prohibited from using TOP 1 for performance reasons, but then it's okay to accept an alternate solution that performs poorly as long as it doesn't use TOP 1. <confused>

Answer (score 2):

This makes me feel dirty. It will return a single team name even if there is a tie - if you want all rows in the event of a tie, use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name FROM
(
    SELECT 
        TeamID, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY c DESC)
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TeamID, c = COUNT(*) 
        FROM dbo.TeamMember GROUP BY TeamID
    ) AS x
) AS y
INNER JOIN dbo.Team AS t
ON y.TeamID = t.ID
WHERE y.rn = 1; -- **EDIT** forgot the most important part!
```

I'd really stand up and challenge the "no TOP 1" rule. Ask the person who told you it was for performance reasons to compare the performance of your existing query with any of the kludges we've come up with.

Comment: http://www.johnsansom.com/performance-comparison-of-select-top-1-verses-max/#axzz1Y3YazbuK

Comment: So one very specific case with a concocted 1,000,000 row table has guided a policy to affect all future queries? What you *should* do is do the same thing John did... *TEST* all of the options and choose the one that is best for *your* data, *your* indexes, *your* query, and *your* statistics. Don't let one specific result dictate query rules to govern every single line of code you write. (Also, that is just a top 1 against a column, not a top 1 against an aggregate!)

Comment: I think since I am doing a TOP 1 on a COUNT and not the field itself any clustered index will not help.

Comment: I still think it's worthy of testing since it is a *very* different scenario than John's test. This is like saying don't ever eat bananas because one time you had a rotten one...

Comment: @Aaron: It's more like "Don't eat bananas because *someone* once had a rotten one". :) +1 on the answer, although I would use RANK() instead of DENSE_RANK() to account for ties. Only the top value should be taken and either RANK() or DENSE_RANK() would suit well, but I always thought that of the two RANK() should be faster (though not sure how much).

Comment: @Andriy thanks, you're probably right about RANK(), just threw it out there as an aside. I also ran some considerable testing here: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/15/why-generalizations-are-dangerous.aspx

Answer (score 1):

TOP 1 is cleanest way. Here's a really convoluted way that might work:

```
SELECT ID FROM (

SELECT ID, Tally, MAX(Tally) over (partition by ID) AS MaxTally
  FROM (SELECT t1.ID,
               COUNT(t2.ID) AS Tally
          FROM @Team t1
          JOIN @TeamMember t2
            ON t2.TeamID = t1.ID
         GROUP BY t1.ID) x

) y WHERE Tally = MaxTally
```

Comment: Note that you might get more than one row -- if there are multiple teams with the same number of members. Your TOP 1 version handles this issue by just picking one when there are ties.

Comment: He could add ROW_NUMBER() and pick the one where the ROW_NUMBER() = 1 to circumvent that :)

Comment: I can't get this example to return a single row. I think the `partition by` is making it group differently than you think.